# How can I make Capital letter ( upper-case ) permalinks?

Tags: wordpress

How can I make a link like this?

http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/About

the "Using_Permalinks" part, A is Capital letters. But WP automatically convert upper case  to lower case.

`http://www.lifecellskin.us/Dev/about`

I'm trying to convert an old site that made by only html to a WP platform site. Some links to the site look like this:

http://www.lifecellskin.us/About

The site is already indexed by SEO. so I don't want to lose SE rankings.

Thanks for reading this, and hope somebody will be able to shed some light on it...

Answer (score 0):

I am giving the answer of my own question because I figure out the soloution.

Here is a function given below add this function to
     `wp-includes->formating.php'

```
      function sanitize_title_with_dashes($title) {
          $title = strip_tags($title);
           // Preserve escaped octets.
           $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
          // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
         $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
         // Restore octets.
          $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

         $title = remove_accents($title);
            if (seems_utf8($title)) {
             //if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
           //    $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
    //}
        $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
}

//$title = strtolower($title);
$title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
$title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
// Keep upper-case chars too!
$title = preg_replace('/[^%a-zA-Z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
$title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
$title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
$title = trim($title, '-');

return $title;
```

}

This function is already exist in formatting.php comment out that and add the above function.
Thanks

Comment: you may want to search a way for using hooks, because you will have problems at next update ;)

Comment: @Ionut Staicu:Is there is any problem with this soloution?

Comment: No, but you will loose all changes on next update (or you will need to re-edit this file again, on each update) :)

Comment: there is a filter `sanitize_title`, Use that

Comment: Ya You are very right But What I do its client requirement I am not figure out anything else.So I changed this file.

Comment: @atif089:how to use`sanitize_title`.Not clear what you want to say

Comment: This really isn't ideal, but I can't find another way to do it. sanitize_title_with_dashes has no hooks... I think you have to hack it like shalu did.

Answer (score -1):

File : wp-includes/formatting.php

**Line 826**

```
$title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment out that line

Comment: After comment out  this lin.Its again take lower case when I edit permalink for pages throught admin.

Comment: A few lines later, there is another line to comment out:  
    $title = strtolower($title);  
  
And then near the end of the function, there is a regexp to which "A-Z" needs to be added:  
    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);  
becomes  
    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-zA-Z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);

Comment: Also, the line numbers have changed in the mean time.